# Is there any definition for $(\hat{a}^{\dagger} \pm \hat{a})^{n}\hat{S} \left | 0 \right> $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

Specifically, I want to apply the following operators

$\hat{P}^n = \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger} -  \hat{a}  \right)^n \tag{1},$ 
$\hat{X}^n = \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger} +  \hat{a}  \right)^n \tag{2},$ 
(with the power $n=1,2, \cdots$ and $\hat{a},\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ the annihilation, creation operators) to a squeezed vacum state $\left | 0 \right>  $, that is

$\hat{P}^n \hat{S} \left | 0 \right> = \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger} -  \hat{a}  \right)^n \hat{S} \left | 0 \right> \tag{3},$
$\hat{X}^n \hat{S} \left | 0 \right> = \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger} +  \hat{a}  \right)^n \hat{S} \left | 0 \right> \tag{4},$
where $\hat{S}$ is the well known squeezed operator, defined by $\hat{S}=\exp\left[\frac{1}{2}(\xi^{\ast}\hat{a}^{2} - \xi\hat({a}^{\dagger})^2 )\right],$ with $\xi=r e^{i\theta}.$ So, the question is: **Is there any trick, identity or whatever, in order to expand the right-hand side of equations (3) and (4)?**

Comment: On approach is to write the commutator of $S$ with $X^n$ and $P^n$. If the commutator's action on $|0\rangle$ is simple enough, things will work. I guess
using Baker Campbell Hausdorff you can do this. but I am not sure. You should check it out if you have never seen it before.

Comment: $\hat{S}$ in your question is not a squeeze operator, rather it is a displacement operator.

Comment: @Sunyam, you're right, I forgot to put the squares in the annihilation and creation operators. I already corrected this

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
$$ e^{A}  B \ e^{-A} = B+[A,B]+\frac{[A,[A,B]]}{2!}+\dots $$

With $ A = - \frac{1}{2}(\xi^{\ast}\hat{a} - \xi\hat{a}^{\dagger} )$, $B = (a^{\dagger}-\hat{a})$, the above formula yields,
$$ (\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\hat{a})\hat{S} = \hat{S}(\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\hat{a})+\frac{(\xi-\xi^*)}{2} \hat{S}. $$

Repetitive application will recursively produce the answer.

You can also play the same game with $\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}$.